# How to allow access to selected REST URLs in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

I have a number of REST controllers built with Spring MVC, say for example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "employee")
EmplyoeeController

@RequestMapping(value = "office")
OfficeController

@RequestMapping(value = "school")
SchoolController

@RequestMapping(value = "admin")
AdminController

@RequestMapping(value = "report")
ReportController
```

Only `.../api/admin` and `.../api/report` resources should be available for anyone.
I donot want to remove or comment request mappings in my other controllers.  How could  I achieve this in web.xml

The problem is we are releasing a lite version of our web-app, but bundled with a number of controllers. In our spring-security.xml we have:

```
<security:intercept-url
  pattern="/api/**"
  access="isAuthenticated()"
/>
```

If the user is authenticated then that will allow them to access all resources under `/api/**` - like `/api/admin` and also `/api/office`, `/api/school` `/api/employee`, and so on...
The functionality we want the authenticated users to access is only `/api/admin` and `/api/report` and nothing else even if they are authenticated.
We donot need any ROLEs to be assigned for the users yet.

Comment: <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern><url-pattern>/report/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring Security for this. Tutorial here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/.

In web.xml you would add this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        some.package.LocalSecurityConfig
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And you would define LocalSecurityConfig like this:

```
package some.package;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class LocalSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> configurer = new InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder>();

    configurer.withUser("user").password("password").authorities("ROLE_USER");

    auth.apply(configurer);
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/employee", "/office", "/school").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll().and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
}
```